# Compatibility error when importing picasso library to android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libraries, picasso

this is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.villegas.juliana.dreavel_app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

when i copy the picasso dependency it throws this error in this line

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

error : All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 24.0.0, 23.4.0. Examples include com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0 and com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:23.4.0 more... (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>)

Comment: It is possible the support-v4 library is imported using API 24 from the picasso library

Comment: Try updating compileSdk and targetSdk to 25, and update buildtools and appcompat library to the newest version